# CRM 2011 KeyNotFoundException exception

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, keynotfoundexception, query-expressions

I am new to CRM development.
I have a Custom Entity "customer". This Entity has a Field called "defaultcustomer", which can be TRUE or FALSE. I am working on a Plug-In where i need to set the "defaultcustomer" to FALSE for all the "Customers". I am doing it as below:

**FACTS:**

I have registered the plugin for the entity "customer" itself. So when the Entity "customer" is updated, the plugin fires.

```csharp
private void MakeAllNonDefault()
{

    try
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("customer");
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("defaultcustomer");

        EntityCollection retrieved = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        foreach (Entity myCustomer in retrieved.Entities)
        {

            myCustomer["defaultcustomer"] = false;
            service.Update(myCustomer);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in MakeAllNonDefault(): " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**
    It throws error on this line:

```
myCustomer["defaultcustomer"] = false;

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: This type of error goes away if you use early-binding and cast your returned entities to instances of your `Customer` entity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that particular field is not present in the collection of properties. In CRM, only properties that have been set or updated are included.

Try something like:

```cs
foreach (Entity myCustomer in retrieved.Entities)
{
    if (myCustomer.Attributes.ContainsKey("defaultcustomer"))
    {
        myCustomer["defaultcustomer"] = false;
    }
    else
    {
        myCustomer.Attributes.Add("defaultcustomer", false);
    }
    service.Update(myCustomer);
}
```

Comment: This is possible even though he explicitly includes that attribute in the `ColumnSet` of a new `QueryExpression`?

Comment: @PeterMajeed - as far as I know, if there is no value in the field, it will not be returned.

Comment: @glosrob: Maybe this is another reason not to use late-binding. Our group doesn't use late-binding at all, but I would expect if you explicitly include the attribute and that attribute's value is `NULL`, the attribute would be present in the attribute collection with a value of `NULL` and would be available for value assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Have you double checked that the field really is called defaultcustomer?

If it's a custom entity then it's likely the field begins with a prefix, for instance new_defaultcustomer. Make sure you are using the name of the field, not the display name.

Comment: Actually that is a very good point. If it is a custom entity, all fields (other than the default createdby, created etc.) will, as far as I know, have a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @glosrob seems fine. Are you still getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary"?

Try to use ITracingService to get more information about the plugin execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

While Update all Crm fields are False accept that what you Update the field. For that you can use Pre/Post Images in Plugin. you will found that crm field key and update what you need.