# How to make an entity update its own field

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'd like to change a value of `field_1` in case the user changed the `field_2`. Normally, one does that on the client using JS **but** in this case, the user might change his mind again, back to the original value. So, I'd like to update a field in a plugin.

I'm successfully discovering the change in `field_2` but when I assign a value to `field_1`, it doesn't get stored in the database. What do I do wrong?

```
if (IsField_2Changed())
   (Context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity).Attributes["field_1"] = 666;
```

I get no crashes, no complaints **but** the value of 666 (because it's Halloween) does't get stored to the database. The code is executed on the message of update.

Please note that the user doesn't change `field_1`. It's going to be set as a read-only field later on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRM 2011 KeyNotFoundException exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901527/crm-2011-keynotfoundexception-exception).

Comment: @PeterMajeed Not really, Peter. Not this time, hihi. I don't get any errors at all. The field **is** found (despite my problems with not finding stuff the last few days). It's written to as well. **However**, the value that I stick into the target entity doesn't get stored to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of guess as you don't mention how your plugin is registered.

However I'm guessing the plugin is registered on the Post when it should be on the Pre.

If you want to update by using the Target you need to do it in the Pre.

If your plugin has to be on the Post, use a webservice update call.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*using a webservice update call*"? Since I prefer not to put my plugin on pre-state (of fear for what the rest of the code would do if I change my basic assumption on when it gets executed) I've resolved the issue by simply re-updating the entity. Of course, one has to be careful not to cause recurrence (I know that for a fact, a very painful fact) but other than that, it seems to work. Then I got thinking - **maybe James had an even better idea**, so I'm asking straight out.

Comment: By "using a webservice update call" I meant issuing a SOAP or REST request, e.g. `service.Update(entity)`. Which is probably what you are doing already. If I have understood this correctly: "I've resolved the issue by simply re-updating the entity". Plugins repeatedly triggering themselves is just something that has to be handled, usually by checking the `IExecutionContext.Depth` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about `IExecutionContext.Depth`. I'll try that the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside JavaScript.  Just add your function to the OnChange event of field2.  It is not an OnBlur event, so it will only fire when the user leaves the field after changing.

If you need to fire every time the user leaves the field, you can also bind to the OnBlur event via JavaScript (not with the fields on change event), but it's unsupported.

For the plugin though, here's a nice walk through (although the logic isn't exactly the same)
http://nzcrmguy.blogspot.com/2011/03/updating-fields-on-crm-2011-plugin.html

Comment: Naa, JS won't do in this case. I need to solve it using a plugin. I'll take a look at the walk-though but I'm having a suspicion that I got it right just except for some minor detail. And **boy** that one one sloppy and ugly formatting on that blog. :)